# Extracting Small amount of Heavy records from BigQueyr

Tags: java, performance, google-bigquery

I want to load 1 record that has 1.8MB of data from BigQuery query result to Java, currently I am using code like

```
@Autowired
BigQuery bigQuery;
         
QueryJobConfiguration queryJobConfiguration = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
                .setDefaultDataset(bigQueryProperties.getDatasetName())
                .setUseQueryCache(true)
                .setNamedParameters(queryParametersMap)
                .setJobTimeoutMs(jobTimeoutMs)
                .build();

bigQuery.query(queryJobConfiguration)
```

I know this code is better to be used for a large number of lightweight records
So I am interested if there is any better approach in case we have just 1 but a very big record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [BigQuery Storage Read API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage). According to the documentation, "the BigQuery Storage Read API provides a third option that represents an improvement over prior options. When you use the Storage Read API, structured data is sent over the wire in a binary serialization format. This allows for additional parallelism among multiple consumers for a set of results."
 
Here's an [example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/libraries#use) in using the client library.